# SQL Query for Display nested Subjects

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Output has only 2 columns

1. Text: Displayed in image
2. Id: ID of the last subject (last child)

```
CREATE TABLE Subjects (
    SubjectId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Subject VARCHAR(70),
    ParentSubjectId INT,
    IsActive BIT,
    CreatedDate DATETIME,
    CreatedBy INT,
    UpdatedDate DATETIME,
    UpdatedBy INT
);



INSERT INTO Subjects (Subject, ParentSubjectId) VALUES ('Accountancy',0);

INSERT INTO Subjects (Subject, ParentSubjectId) VALUES ('Accounting',1);
INSERT INTO Subjects (Subject, ParentSubjectId) VALUES ('Bookkipping',1);
INSERT INTO Subjects (Subject, ParentSubjectId) VALUES ('Payroll',1);

INSERT INTO Subjects (Subject, ParentSubjectId) VALUES ('Sage Payroll',4);



SELECT * FROM Subjects
```

[image: output image]

Comment: Ηi and welcome! Please describe what is the problem your are facing and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please add your used DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH mysubjects as (
   SELECT 0 as i, s.SubjectId, cast(s.[Subject] as varchar(max)) as "Subject"
   from Subjects s
   where ParentSubjectId=0
   union all 
   SELECT i+1, s.SubjectId, CONCAT(c1.[Subject],'-',s.Subject) 
   from mysubjects c1 
   inner join Subjects s on s.ParentSubjectId=c1.SubjectId and c1.subjectId>i-1
   where i<2  
   )
select * 
from mysubjects;
```

output:

```
i           SubjectId   Subject
----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------
0           1           Accountancy
1           2           Accountancy-Accounting
1           3           Accountancy-Bookkipping
1           4           Accountancy-Payroll
2           5           Accountancy-Payroll-Sage Payroll
```